# Showing that the set of integers with an odd number of 2s in their factorizations is primitive recursive

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Knowing that:
$p(i)$, the $i^{th}$ prime function, $\pi_i(m)$, the exponent of prime $p(i)$,and any other basic primitive recursive function hold, how could a primitive recursive relation be built for the above? Any hits would be great. Thank you

Comment: So you are given that the function that returns the exponent of a prime $p$ in the prime factorisation of a natural number $n$ is primitive recursive. What aspect of applying that function to determine the exponent of $2$ in the prime factorisation of a given $n$ and then deciding whether that exponent is odd are you having problems with?

Comment: @RobArthan I can't determine how to construct a characteristic function to simply say "x is odd." i feel like i must be overthinking

Comment: @RobArthan nevermind. I just figured it out with exponentiation

Comment: Well done! Why not write it up as an answer here?

Comment: @RobArthan done- I'm sure there is a nicer way, but my professor said the way I did it does the trick still, and she's a logician, so I'll take it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already know $O$ to be the zero function, which is primitive recursive. Let $D$ be the relation that will output $0$ if $y$ is odd, and $1$ if $y$ is even. Note That $E(x,y)$ is also known to be primitive recursive. Let $\chi_D$ denote the characteristic function of the relation $D$. $\chi_D(0) = E(0,0) = 1$. $\chi_D(Sy) = E(0,\chi_D(y))$. If $y$ is odd, $\chi_D(y) = 0$ and thus $\chi_D(Sy) = E(0,0) = 1$. If $y$ is even, $\chi_D(y) = 1$ and thus $\chi_D(Sy) = 0 \rightarrow y+1$ is odd. So $D$ is primitive recursive.

Let $T$ be the set of integers with an odd number of twos in their prime factorization. Let $\chi_T(m)$ be the characteristic function which outputs 0 if $m \in T$, and $1$ otherwise. Let $\pi_1(m)$ denote the number of $2s$ in the prime factorization of $m$.

$\chi_T(0) = \chi_D(\pi_1(0)) = \chi_D(0) = 1.$ 
$\chi_T(Sy) = \chi_D(\pi_1(A(S0,y))).$ So $\chi_T$ is also primitive recursive, and $T$ is primitive recursive.

Comment: I am reading $E(x, y)$ as being the prim. rec. function that is $1$ when $x = y$ and $0$ otherwise. Is that right? If so, it looks good to me. Many people would economise a bit by defining $\chi_D(0) = 1$ and $\chi_D(Sx) = 1 - \chi_D(x)$, but that's just an arithmetic trick.

Comment: @RobArthan correct! and yes, I definitely agree- the book I am using is a bit unorthodox in that it likes to define characteristic functions in a manner that seems to go against one's intuition, in terms of the boolean output (A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic)